# React - How to filter a button

Tags: reactjs

I'm working through some React tutorials and trying to figure out how to filter buttons out of a button group by searching for a term. My filter function works for text but I can't figure out how to get it to work with buttons.

```
<div className="searchbar">
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." onChange={this.searchHandler} />
  </form>
  { 
    this.state.drinks.filter(searchingFor(this.state.term)).map(drink =>
      <div key={ drink.id } >
        { drink.title }
      </div>)
  }
</div>
```

I am able to filter text with this (drink.title) but I want to filter the buttons in the section below. Is this possible with what I currently have? Sorry if this is a vague question, I'm brand new to React and would appreciate any help.

```
<Grid.Column className="left-col" width="3">  
  <Container >      
    <Menu >
      {drinks && drinks.length
        ? <Button.Group vertical widths={drinks.length} >
          {Object.keys(drinks).map((key) => {                 
            return <Button size="large" fluid active={drink && drink.id === drinks[key].id} key={key} onClick={()=>this.getDrink(drinks[key].id)}>
                      {drinks[key].title}
                   </Button>
                 })}
          </Button.Group>
        : <Container textAlign='center'>No drinks found. 
          </Container>
      }
    </Menu>
  </Container>
</Grid.Column>
```

and the search function

```
function searchingFor(term) {
  return function(x) {
    return x.title.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) || !term
  }
}
```

Comment: In the first code block you are filtering `this.state.drinks` then rendering the results in a `.map()` function. Why can't you do that with the button code block?

Comment: You're applying the `map` method, not then `filter` method. Try it out with `filter` instead